# I'm trying to make a book listing android app, but nothing shows up on the emulator

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I just started to learn android and currently trying to make a book listing app that can fetch data using URL, I'm currently using a customized arrayadapter(bookadapter) and listview and customized asynctask(bookasynstask). I'm expecting to see some information on the emulator but the only thing I saw on the emulation is the book list layout without any information regarding books.

This is is BookAdapter class

```
public class BookAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Book> {

    public BookAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Book> books) {
        super(context, 0, books);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView==null){
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.book_item,parent,false);
        }
        Book book = getItem(position);
        ImageView image = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.iamge_view);
        //haven't figured out how to set image from url yet.
        image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        TextView title = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_view);
        title.setText(book.getTitle1());
        TextView authors = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.author_view);
        authors.setText(book.getAuthors());
        TextView info = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.info);
        info.setText(book.getInfo());
        TextView year = listItemView.findViewById(R.id.year_view);
        year.setText(book.getYear());
        return listItemView;
    }

}
```

This is the main activity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private static final String GOOGLE_BOOK="https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=science";
    private BookAdapter bookAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bookAdapter = new BookAdapter(MainActivity.this, new ArrayList<Book>());
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setAdapter(bookAdapter);
        BookAsyncTask task = new BookAsyncTask();
        task.execute(GOOGLE_BOOK);
    }
    private class BookAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Book>> {
        @Override
        protected List<Book> doInBackground(String... urls) {
            if (urls.length < 1 | urls[0] == null) {
                return null;
            }
            List<Book> data = QueryUtils.fetchBookData(urls[0]);
            return data;
        }

        protected void OnPostExecute(List<Book> data) {
            bookAdapter.clear();
            // If there is a valid list of {@link Earthquake}s, then add them to the adapter's
            // data set. This will trigger the ListView to update.
            if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
                bookAdapter.addAll(data);
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

This is the util class to fetch data from google books

```
public class QueryUtils {
    public QueryUtils(){
    }
    private static final String LOG_TAG = QueryUtils.class.getSimpleName();
    public static List<Book> fetchBookData(String requestUrl){
        URL url = createUrl(requestUrl);
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try{
            jsonResponse = makeHttpUrl(url);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing input stream", e);
        }
        List<Book> books = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);
        return books;
    }
    private static URL createUrl(String requestUrl){
        URL url = null;
        try{
            url = new URL(requestUrl);
        }catch (MalformedURLException e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error with creating URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }
    private static String makeHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {
        String jsonResponse = null;
        if (url == null){
            return jsonResponse;
        }
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode()==200){
                inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                jsonResponse = readFromStream(inputStream);
            }else {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
            }} catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the Book JSON results.", e);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (inputStream != null) {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }
    private static String readFromStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        if (inputStream!=null){
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                output.append(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
    private  static ArrayList<Book> extractFeatureFromJson(String bookJson){
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty((bookJson))){
            return null;
        }
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject baseJsonObject = new JSONObject(bookJson);
            JSONArray items = baseJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");

            for(int i = 0;i < items.length();i++){
                JSONObject bookItem = items.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject volumeInfo = bookItem.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                String [] authors = new String[]{};
                JSONArray authorJsonArray = volumeInfo.optJSONArray("authors");
                if(authorJsonArray!= null) {
                    ArrayList<String> authorList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < authorJsonArray.length(); j++) {
                        authorList.add(authorJsonArray.get(j).toString());
                    }
                    authors = authorList.toArray(new String[authorList.size()]);
                }
                String date = volumeInfo.getString("publishedDate");
                JSONObject imageLink = volumeInfo.getJSONObject("imageLinks");
                String image = imageLink.getString("thumbnail");
                String infoLink = "";
                if(volumeInfo.optString("infoLink")!=null)
                    infoLink = volumeInfo.optString("infoLink");
                Book book = new Book(title,authors,infoLink,date,image);
                books.add(book);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("QueryUtils", "Problem parsing the book JSON results", e);
        }
        return books;

    }
}
```

This is is main activity layout which is a listview

```
<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
</ListView>
```

This is the list item view layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iamge_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/BookElement"
        tools:text="title"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/BookElement"
        tools:text="info"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/BookElement"
        tools:text="Authors"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/BookElement"
        tools:text="year"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And log information

```
    10-18 15:05:28.241 19667-19667/? I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-18 15:05:28.256 19667-19667/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
10-18 15:05:28.286 19667-19674/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
10-18 15:05:28.417 19667-19667/? I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-18 15:05:28.651 19667-19691/? D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-18 15:05:28.670 19667-19694/? D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
10-18 15:05:28.941 19667-19694/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-18 15:05:28.941 19667-19694/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-18 15:05:28.950 19667-19694/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-18 15:05:28.950 19667-19694/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0

                                                   [ 10-18 15:05:29.059  1604: 1629 D/         ]
                                                   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x929ed300, tid 1629


                                                   [ 10-18 15:05:29.061  1604: 1629 W/         ]
                                                   Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 
10-18 15:05:29.093 19667-19694/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa3cfe3a0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
10-18 15:05:29.383 19667-19694/com.example.android.booklisting D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3cfe3a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa392ab20)
10-18 15:05:29.453 19667-19667/com.example.android.booklisting I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-18 15:05:29.538 19667-19694/com.example.android.booklisting D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3cfe3a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa392ab20)
```

Comment: In the OnPostExecute(List<Book> data), add a toast or log to show the size of data, this help you to know if your data is empty or view is not updated. In addition, after your  bookAdapter.addAll(data);, you need to call bookAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged() to update the view. Hope that help!